# Change object's axes after rotating it in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am rotating an 3D object in three.js on the X and Y axes by click dragging and using the method `rotateOnAxis`. After I rotate, I want to reset the axes so that when I click drag again, it's as if the axes are in their original directions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can be done using quaternion. I found an example showing what I want to accomplish here: https://github.com/defmech/Three.js-Object-Rotation-with-Quaternion